# Try to sort a result with a count on a manytomany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to do a count on a many-to-many relation and after order the result by it.

Here is my relation Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="QuoteBox\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="likedQuotes")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="JNT_liker",
 *     joinColumns={
 *         @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *             name="QUOTE_id",
 *             referencedColumnName="QUOTE_id",
 *             nullable=false
 *         )
 *     },
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="USER_id", referencedColumnName="USER_id", nullable=false)}
 * )
 */
private $likers;
```

Here is my Repository method :

```
/**
 * Find All by number of Likes Adapter
 * @return Pagerfanta
 */
public function findAllByLikesAdapter(Location $location)
{
    $query = $this->getCommonQuery($location);
    $query->select('q, count(q.likers) as HIDDEN num_like');
    $query->innerJoin('q.likers', 'likers');
    $query->groupBy('q.id');
    $query->orderBy('num_like', 'ASC');
    return new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($query));
}
```

Here is my controller :

```
    public function topAction(Location $location, $page = 1)
    {
    $pager = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("QuoteBoxQuoteBundle:Quote")->findAllByLikesAdapter($location);
    $pager->setMaxPerPage(5);
    $pager->setCurrentPage($page);
    return [ 'pager' => $pager, 'location' => $location ];
    }
```

Here is my view using twig and pagerfanta :

```
{% for quote in pager.currentPageResults %}
    {% include "QuoteBoxQuoteBundle:line:quote.html.twig" with {'quote':quote, 'currentPage':pager.currentPage } only %}
{% endfor %}
```

And when I execute it here is the error :

```
> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'likers) as HIDDEN': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.") in QuoteBoxQuoteBundle:Quotes:quotes.html.twig at line 13.
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Try `count(linkers.id)` instead of `count(q.likers)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you all.

It works, Here is my solution

```
    $query = $this->getCommonQuery($location);
    $query->addSelect('q, COUNT(likers.id) AS HIDDEN num_likers');
    $query->leftJoin('q.likers', 'likers');
    $query->groupBy('q.id');
    $query->orderBy('num_likers', 'DESC');
```

I had to add leftJoin instead of join in order to have all of my quotes.

Answer (score 0):

***Maybe*** : Change `q.likers` by `likers`

```
$query = $this->getCommonQuery($location);
$query->select('q, count(likers) as HIDDEN num_like');  // <-- HERE
$query->innerJoin('q.likers', 'likers');    // Because you called it 'likers' here
$query->groupBy('q.id');
$query->orderBy('num_like', 'ASC');
return new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($query));
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/ here is the error :

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 152 near 'likers IS NOT': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.") in QuoteBoxQuoteBundle:Quotes:quotes.html.twig at line 13.

Comment: "'likers IS NOT'" is not a part of your dql, can you share the code you wrote ?